# docker images shows an unexpected created time

Tags: docker

I don't understand the created information when I do

```
docker image ls
```

When I have just created an image by doing

```
docker build . -t sometag
```

The created will show up with a "created" which is certainly not just a moment ago.

So I try to

```
docker image prune
```

And also to clear the builder "cache"?

```
docker builder prune
```

But none of it helps to create an image that was created now!

If I do

```
docker build --no-cache -t sometag
```

I can get a new image with a fresh "created".

Can someone explain how "created" works and why it shows up with a totally different time than I would expect. I mean - I just flushed everything, right ? But I still get a totally different result than I would expect - because I just did a fresh "docker build ."

What is going on ?

Comment: Is the time out by an integer number of hours?

Comment: ^Yes. In my case which I know will differ from user to user, is 25 hours.

Comment: That's weird. Timezone problem?